# Need to recover older $PATH setting

Tags: path, recover

I have just installed an app which overwrote my $PATH variable... so now, a bunch of stuff will not work.  While I have a full backup, I am hoping that there is an easier approach than to restore, get the PATH, the "roll it forward" again.

Is there a location in the windows registry (or anywhere else) that stores an older $PATH setting?

Thanks,
GS

Comment: As far as I know, the only "backup" registry files that exist outside of system restore points are in \windows\system32\config, and are created at first-install, then left alone - this backup'd be unlikely to have your custom path in it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I found the answer...
using REGEDIT, it is under
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment or
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Session Manager\Environment

In my case, it was under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002...

GS

Comment: This answer has just saved me from terrible OS fixing job! And my case is same as the original answer, not sure whether it is a coincidence or some other reasons.

Comment: i dont have a controlset002

Comment: I have a path variable under controlset001, but its the wrong one. after i accidentally deleted System Path i made the mistake of copying and setting System Path to User Path. Should I delete the incorrect Path before doing a system restore?

Answer (score -2):

type in cmd:

```
set path=%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
```

above code will set the path temporarily. To set permanently, add `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;` to **System Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables**

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to provide more explanation to your answers. See [How to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help in improving your answer.

Comment: doesnt help restore the custom path variable before deletion