# all the basic commands (ls, cd, ..., as well as vi, vim) not working after modifying the Path file

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, sml

I was in the process of installing SML on my personal laptop, and I modified the path file. Now, all of the basic commands don't work.
i.e)
-bash: ls: command not found

How do I reset everything?

Comment: Which "path file" ? What is its own path ? May be could you could first `PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin` ?

Comment: Duplicate of [Need to recover older $PATH setting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956365/need-to-recover-older-path-setting). Also, this problem is quite unrelated to Standard ML. :)

Comment: @SimonShine That other question seems to be about Windows whereas this one seems to be about Linux. But -- you are of course right that it really has nothing to do with ML.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. It's a duplicate of [Linux wrong path exported. How to recover ~./bashrc file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361937/linux-wrong-path-exported-how-to-recover-bashrc-file) then. :-P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux wrong path exported. How to recover ~./bashrc file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361937/linux-wrong-path-exported-how-to-recover-bashrc-file)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the better option is to reboot with live distro, mount your root file system, revert the change to the path file and than reboot your system

Comment: That sounds completely overkill. Presumably the PATH variable was messed up either in the immediate shell (in which case a new terminal can simply be opened), or in ~/.bashrc, in which case a non-bash shell (e.g. sh) can be opened in order to fix that file. Either way, this question was asked and answered multiple times before.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create environment for your new path or change your directory `cd <new path>` to new path.

Follow [this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/7.0/chapter04/settingenvironment.html) url to create environment